# How to check database version with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, database, typescript, orm, mariadb

Is it possible to check the database version with TypeScript / TypeORM? I am using MariaDB.

I would like to compare the current version with a list of supported versions of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with TypeScript, and I don't know if it stores the version submitted during client/server handshake but you should be able to retrieve the version by executing SQL statements `SELECT VERSION()` or `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version'`.

Comment: I wanted to try it out with the ORM, but thx! You're right, it's easier that way. I also tried to find a list of supported versions of the MariaDB, but couldn't find any APIs they offer for this. Do you know maybe where I could look? I could write it in a JSON by hand and check once in a while if there are changes (but I wanted to automate it). Thanks!